# $\mathbb{E} \int_a^b W^3(t)\,dW(t)=?$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Is it true that

$\mathbb{E} \int_a^b W^3(t)\,dW(t)=0$, for $a < b \in \mathbb{R}$

I know that for an adapted process $\Delta(t), t\geq 0$, the integral

$\int_0^t \Delta(u)dW(u)$ is a martingale in $t$, and therefore had expectation $0$, if

$\mathbb{E} \int_0^T \Delta^2(t) dt < \infty$

How can I show the square-integrability condition, and is there an other way to show the expectation?

Comment: If $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,t)$, then $\Bbb E(|X|^6) = |t|^3\Bbb E(|\mathcal{N}(0,1)|^6)$. No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interchanging integral and mean (tonelli) gives us $\int_0^T E[W(t)^6]dt=\int_0^T 15 t^3 dt =15/4 \cdot T^4< \infty$ where we have used [this scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments) to find the 6'th moment.

Comment: How is Tonelli/Fubini justified here?

Comment: $P$ and the lebesque measure are $\sigma-$finite, $W^6\geq 0$ and jointly measurable. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, you are not wrong. I was just looking for something more general for when one has f(W(t)) instead of W^3(t) inside.

Comment: Ahh.. Okay. There are different tricks from above when $f \geq 0$ we use tonelli. If say f is continuous an useful trick is f(W) is continuous so bounded on compact sets. Often times it is also possible to use ito or ito's product rule to express the integral as something else e.g. $W(t)^2=2\int_0^t W(s) dW(s)+t$ so $\int_0^t W(s) dW(s)= \frac{1}{2} (W(t)^2-t)$ so a martingale. That's the 3 tricks I use the most I think.